# do not reuse tab in case target is _BLANK

Tags: php, html, tabs, href

I have 2 php pages:
1.home page
2.view page

On the home page I have thumbnails of featuring items and each item has a link to its view page, differentiated by a GET parameter. i.e.: viewpage.php?id=1, viewpage.php?id=2, etc...

I use  because I need the view pages to open in new tabs or new browsers (doesn't matter which)

As i click on the first item, its view page opens normally in a new tab; however, as I click on the second item it replaces the tab of the first item.

How can I force my home page to open each view page in a new separate tab?

Comment: Can we have your  form code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about what you are asking, but try this javascript function instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('A[rel="_blank"]').click(function(){
            window.open($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It yields the same result.

My problem is that the browser is REUSING the tab page (opened by the first item's view page) to open the second page targeted to _blank, while it should create a second, third, fourth... tabs on each click...

I believe it's somehow related to my href link being the same (viewpage.php)

Comment: <a href="viewpage.php?id=1" target="_blank">item 1</a>
    <a href="viewpage.php?id=2" target="_blank">item 2</a>

Answer (score 0):

You should use lower case. "_blank" instead of "_BLANK".

Read more about [Link options](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Training/Link_options).